# Why is rising edge preferred over falling edge

Tags: hardware, vhdl, synthesis

Flip-Flops(,Registers ...) are usually triggered by a rising or falling edge. But mostly in code you see an if-clause which uses the rising edge triggering. In fact i never saw a code with falling edge.

Why is that? Is it because naturally the programmers use rising edge, because they are used to, or is it because of some physical/analog law/fact, where the rising edge programming is faster/simpler/energy-efficient/... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As zennehoy says, it's convention - but one going back to when logic was done in [discrete chips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits) with a few gates or flipflops within them.  Those packages of flipflops were always rising-edge triggered...as far as I recall, but maybe someone with better recollection of the yellow books will correct me!

[image: The TI Logic databooks]

So when synthesis came along, no doubt everyone felt comfortable carrying on that way!

Answer (score 4):

Nothing more than a matter of convention.

Using the rising edge is more common, and most component libraries use the rising edge. This means that using those libraries requires you to also use rising edges, or add clock synchronization logic, or keep your paths so short that the delay is less than half a clock cycle. Just using rising edges everywhere is by far the easiest.

Answer (score 3):

When you design a (single-edge) DFF in a chip, you must choose at which (rising or falling) clock edge it will operate. This decision is independent from the implementation approach (i.e., master-slave or pulsed-latch), and it does not alter the number of transistors in the DFF itself.

Since positive-edge is the typical default (as in FPGAs), to operate at the negative clock edge the usual procedure is to simply use a positive-edge DFF with an inverted version of the clock signal connected to its clock port. If this is done locally (near the DFF clock port), then two extra transistors are indeed needed (to build a CMOS inverter for the clock).

Answer (score 0):

it is somewhat a matter of convention but if you look at the design of falling versus rising edge, there is only a difference of an added inverter, and it turned out to be 2 transistors less on rising edge

but there are designs out there that use both, for example in some data caches you write on rising edge and read on falling edge, or vice-versa depending on design choices!

good question, and try it out or take a course(maybe online) on digital integrated circuits

Comment: No, I don't believe that a rising-edge FF uses fewer transistors than a falling edge FF. For master-slave flip-flops the clock signal must be inverted to the master with respect to the slave, so there must be an inverter someplace. It can be on the clock to the slave (falling edge FF) or the clock to the master (rising edge FF).